# Modular counting of integral points under sparse non-negativity

Tags: computational-complexity, convex-polytopes, integer-programming, positivity, total-unimodularity

Given a polyhedron
$$Ax\geq b$$
where every entry of $A,b$ are non-negative and $A\in\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$ and there are $O(1)$ (say $\leq8$) non-negative entries per row of $A$ is it possible to compute $\bmod2$ the number of integral points in the polyhedron in polynomial time if $m=poly(n)$?

Assume in addition polyhedron is integral and perhaps $A$ is totally unimodular.

Can the algorithm be in $NC^1$?